# Query a backbone collection (or json) from a Filter model (or json)

Tags: json, backbone.js, filtering

I'm trying to render a google map from data I have in a LocationCollection.
Users will define filterParameters in a Model, here is the JSON from a filter

```
var filter = {
    "id_ref_type_category":[2,4],
    "pricemin":5,
    "pricemax":15,
    "distmin":10, // meters
    "distmax":150 // meters
}
```

I need to query my collection, here is a sample of json I have for my location

```
var location = [
{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Sushi 1",
    "price_min":"10",
    "price_max":"20",
    "price_avg":"15",
    "id_ref_type_category":"1",
    "latitude":"48.863831",
    "longitude":"2.356215"
},
{
    "id":"2",
    "description":"Miam ",
    "price_min":"15",
    "price_max":"35",
    "price_avg":"25",
    "id_ref_type_category":"4",
    "latitude":"48.864269",
    "longitude":"2.355153"
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "name":"Restaurant 1",
    "price_min":"5",
    "price_max":"20",
    "price_avg":"12.5",
    "street_number":"60",
    "id_ref_type_category":"1",
    "latitude":"48.863407",
    "longitude":"2.350938"
},
{
    "id":"4",
    "name":"Chez gigi",
    "price_min":"0",
    "price_max":"17",
    "price_avg":"8.5",
    "id_ref_type_category":"2",
    "latitude":"48.861824",
    "longitude":"2.350901"
}
]
```

Regarding to my filter parameter, i am looking for

- a location with a id_ref_type_category equal 2 OR 4
- a location with an average price around 5 and 15
- a location within a distance around 10 and 150 (it's in meters) (if user allow geolocation)

I can calculate the distance from my position to the location with this js function from geocoding http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript

I have looked for backbone collection filtering but didn't find a lot, I have looked for json query systems, but couldn't find any stuff.

I takes any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about applying a underscore filter for all the attributes like in here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cnDeu/1/

I have relaxed a bit your filter object so that a location makes it through.

Essentially the filter looks like this:

```
var filtered = loc.filter(function (el) {
    var dist = distance(el.get('latitude'), el.get('longitude'),
                        position.latitude, position.longitude, 'K') / 1000;

    return ((el.get('id') == filter.id_ref_type_category[0]) ||
        (el.get('id') == filter.id_ref_type_category[1])) &&
        el.get('price_avg') >= filter.pricemin &&
        el.get('price_avg') <= filter.pricemax &&
        dist >= filter.distmin &&
        dist <= filter.distmax;
});
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thx a lot you saved me a lots of time.
I was looking after this plugin : https://github.com/davidgtonge/backbone_query

Your script is perfect, thanks for your help :)
Can you tell me where you did find a valid documentation for filter method on backbone model ?

Comment: Well, Backbone delegates most of its list manipulation functions to **Underscore**, which is a utility library for processing JavaScript arrays and object. Backbone documentation has links to Underscore methods: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods .

Comment: I did read underscore filtering documentation but it wasn't very clear enough for me, I'll be glad if they would have some examples onlines.